# Как добавить исключение в RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, php7, mod-rewrite, rewrite

В моём случае я сам обрабатываю каждый запрос через единый файл index.php, но мне нужно сделать исключения, чтобы при запросах на "/js", "/img", "/css" это правило не срабатывало и открывались соответствующие директории включая "/js/something/else".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*?(\?.*)?$ index.php$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить исключение в **RewriteRule** можно с помощью **RewriteCond**

Если у вас в веб-пространстве только **index.php** + файлы **js** и пр., просто добавьте между вашими строками `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` чтобы если запрошен **существующий** файл - обращаться к нему и не выполнять редирект. То есть если структура такая:

```
/app/   - здесь остальные файлы сайта
/web/   - это корень сайта, доступный по /
   /js/
   /css/
   /img/
   index.php    - сюда все запросы
   .htaccess
```

достаточно просто дописать:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*?(\?.*)?$ index.php$1
```

если же все в куче - тогда, с помощью того же RewriteCond... настраивать редирект

Comment: В целом спасибо. Я прописал: RewriteCond /js/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f и оно работает как мне нужно. И за идею в том числе спасибо.